# How to one track several branches of a tool to a common platform

Tags: perl, architecture

I'm currently working with a tool that over the years has evolved naturally from a number of perl scripts accessed through an apache web server, to a huge collection of tools using a common database and web site (still running apache, but using catalyst instead of CGI).

The problem we're having is that different departments have done local branches from the common main branch for implementing their own new functionality and adaptations.

We're now charged with the task of deciding how a common platform can be made available where certain base functionality is made one track instead of having all these different branches.

These kind of problems must spring up all the time so I'm hoping someone have a good strategy to offer as to how we should continue from here. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general, make sure you have buy in from everybody involved. Trying to do this kind of project without having people on board will just make your life more difficult.

Look for the quick wins. What functionality, if it changed, would have the fastest and clearest beneficial effect across all departments. If it takes you three months to get some good out of it, people won't rate the good results very highly.

Break functionality down as far as you can. One of the biggest problems in forked legacy systems is that a seemingly innocuous change in one place can have huge ramifications elsewhere because of the assumptions made about state. Isolating state in different features should help you out there.